# Python function to choose a file in my PC

Tags: python, file, tkinter, operating-system

I have a Python function that can search a folder in my PC, but I want to transform it in a function that can search for a file, specifically with the DOCX or PDF extensiom (i'll mange that later). This is what I have until now:

```
def choose_file(self):

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    path = askdirectory(title='Choose file')
    os.chdir(path)
```

That opens a Tkinter window that allows me to search for a folder. As I said before, I want to transform it into a tkinter window that searches a DOCX or PDF file, any solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `askopenfilename`. With `askdirectory` you will just get the directory name, so:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def choose_file(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    filetypes=[('DOCX','*.docx'),('PDF','*.pdf')] # Required file types
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose file',filetypes=filetypes)
    # os.chdir(path) There is no need of this now, as specific files will be only selected
```

If you want to choose multiple files then use `askopenfilenames` instead or add an additional option to `askopenfilename`, like:

```
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose file',filetypes=filetypes,multiple=True)
```